# Prevent player rotation from changing last second in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity using C#

In an top down game where the camera rotation is locked, I have made a character controller which is restricted to 8 axis and will only rotate in 45 degree increments. Think Links awakening. Everything works except when moving in a diagonal direction(using WASD).

When I let go of W & D for example, whichever key I let go of last even if by a fraction of a second, the player will end up facing in that direction rather than the intended up and to the right diagonal direction.

I am looking to modify the following code to add some sort of buffer so that the player remains facing the intended direction when I let go of the 2 keys. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

```
        public float defaultSpeed = 6f;
        CharacterController controller;
        private Vector3 playerMovement;
        Vector2 input;
        float angle;
        Quaternion targetRotation;
        Transform cam;    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }    

    public void Movement()
    {
        //Get inputs
        input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        //Only update if keys are pressed
        if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) < deadZone && Mathf.Abs(input.y) < deadZone) return;

        //Get camera angle: input to radians - radians to  degrees - degrees plus the camera angle - limit angle to 45 degree increments
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(input.x, input.y);
        angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle;
        angle += cam.eulerAngles.y;
        angle = Mathf.Round(angle / 45) * 45;

        //Rotate Character
        targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0 );
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;

        //Move Character 
        transform.position += transform.forward * defaultSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a courotine that checks if a key is released, and waits, say 0.5 seconds for another key to be released. If another key is released, then stay in that direction. Hope it works. Good luck.